# Finding a resolvent for clauses

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following question and am not sure how to do it.

Find the resolvent for the two clauses:

$P \vee \neg Q \vee R$

$P \vee \neg R \vee S$

Comment: I'm not into logic, and googling some terms it I couldn't understand what your question is. In specific what do you mean by resolvent for the two clauses? Just guessing what it could mean, observe that it never happens to have both false at the same time.

Comment: This looks like a question to make sure that you have read and understood the definition of a "resolvent". Do you have such a definition in your textbook/notes? Please edit your question to quote that definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvent is the outcome of applying the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29). In your case, there is only one possibility how to apply it:
$$
\frac{P\lor\lnot Q\lor{\boldsymbol R}\qquad P\lor{\boldsymbol {\lnot R}}\lor S}{P\lor\lnot Q\lor S}
$$